# Denormalize XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML fragment:

```
<ExtendedData>
  <Data>
    <displayName>..</displayName>
    <value>..</value>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <displayName>MaxAltitude</displayName>
    <value>4444</value>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <displayName>MinAltitude</displayName>
    <value>3333</value>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <displayName>..</displayName>
    <value>..</value>
  </Data>
</ExtendedData>
```

What I need is a template/function with the result in a form maxAltitude;minAltitude, e.g. 3333;4444 here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the "denormalize" part? It seems like your question is about the very basics of XSLT/XPath.

Comment: the denormalize part is to pick up the data of the value tag next to the tags displayname with values minAltitude and maxAltitude. Both appear ones per ExtendedData block

Comment: IMHO, that's not what [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) means. Regarding your question, you really need to get the basics of XPath first; you will learn the answer in the first 5 minutes of your first lesson.

Answer (score 1):

A template to extract the `value` fields is trivial:

```
<xsl:template match="ExtendedData">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//value"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value"><xsl:value-of select="." />;</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I need the minAltitude and maxAltitude together as one return value - separated via semicolon. Therefore I expect a combination of two matching pattern or something like an iterator e.g. foreach with combined with an if to get the right tags.